# How to reshape a 1 row x column vector into a (900, 1600, 4)?

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, win32gui

I am following a code that grabs the screen on windows and displays it. The github link to the code is : https://github.com/Sentdex/pygta5/blob/ac4132fed5970ce97f0267ecb76eb6bb095ef921/grabscreen.py

When i run the code i get the error ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 1440000 into shape (900,1600,4)

I know the error is due to dimension incompatibility but i do not know how to fix it. The line of code that confuses me is :

```py
img.shape = (height, width, 4) # What is this line trying to do ?
```

P:S Sorry if the format of asking the question might not be up to Stack Overflow standards. I am still getting used to it.

```py
# Done by Frannecklp

import cv2
import numpy as np
import win32gui, win32ui, win32con, win32api


def grab_screen(region=None):

    hwin = win32gui.GetDesktopWindow()

    if region:
            left,top,x2,y2 = region
            width = x2 - left + 1
            height = y2 - top + 1
    else:
        width = win32api.GetSystemMetrics(win32con.SM_CXVIRTUALSCREEN)
        height = win32api.GetSystemMetrics(win32con.SM_CYVIRTUALSCREEN)
        left = win32api.GetSystemMetrics(win32con.SM_XVIRTUALSCREEN)
        top = win32api.GetSystemMetrics(win32con.SM_YVIRTUALSCREEN)

    hwindc = win32gui.GetWindowDC(hwin)
    srcdc = win32ui.CreateDCFromHandle(hwindc)
    memdc = srcdc.CreateCompatibleDC()
    bmp = win32ui.CreateBitmap()
    bmp.CreateCompatibleBitmap(srcdc, width, height)
    memdc.SelectObject(bmp)
    memdc.BitBlt((0, 0), (width, height), srcdc, (left, top), win32con.SRCCOPY)

    signedIntsArray = bmp.GetBitmapBits(True)
    img = np.fromstring(signedIntsArray, dtype='uint8')
    img.shape = (height,width,4)

    srcdc.DeleteDC()
    memdc.DeleteDC()
    win32gui.ReleaseDC(hwin, hwindc)
    win32gui.DeleteObject(bmp.GetHandle())

    return cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGRA2RGB)
```

Comment: As a first step towards fixing this, you should `print (img.shape)` just before that line where you're changing `img.shape`. That might give some clue. Please do that and mention what it prints, by editing your question.

Comment: Thank you for the edit HK boy i was wondering how i could put the import section inside the main code.

Comment: Fountainhead i did do that and it just shows that img is a 1 row 1440000 column vector which i already know.

Comment: You're getting this error because the array has only `900x1600=1440000` elements. Your `reshape` is attempting to "group" them into 4 groups, each containing `1440000` elements -- which is of course not possible. In other words, there are X elements and you are trying to to "group"  them into 4 groups each containing X elements -- which is obviously not possible since there just aren't that many (4 times X) elements.

Comment: When you modify the shape of an array, you're just changing the way the array elements are "grouped" or "arranged" along the dimensions of that array. For example, if you have an array of 12 elements and having a shape of `(4,3)`, you can, if you want, change its shape to `(2,6)` (which still has 12 elements, but arranged differently). But you can't ask for the shape to be changed to `(2,6,5)`, which requires more than 12 elements. You'll have to look deeper into **why** you're doing what you're doing. (That part is something no one else can guess)

Comment: Ahh i see. So if i change the 4 value in the  (900 , 1600 , 4) to 1 then that should solve this issue? But when i do that it gives me the error:

> Unsupported depth of input image:
>     'VDepth::contains(depth)'
> where
>     'depth' is 4 (CV_32S)

Comment: Sincere apologies. I just helped you with your understanding of the shape modification. I do not have the knowledge to help on your overall programming task / problem. Hope someone else can answer.

Comment: No worries Fountainhead thank you very much.